# How does Nginx proxy_pass pass a route parameter

Tags: docker, nginx, endpoint, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm trying to make an api call to an internal docker container, but for every request url I have to make a proxy_pass in the Nginx config. I've read articles that the slashes at the end should work to pass all after de certain url to the proxy_pass.

[Read here (redirect table)](https://dev.to/danielkun/nginx-everything-about-proxypass-2ona)

---

### Example

[www.example.com/api](http://www.example.com/api) -> redirects to correct endpoint

[www.example.com/api/2020](http://www.example.com/api/2020) -> this doesn't redirect to http://api/2020

### Configuration

```
location = /api/ {
   proxy_pass http://api/;
}
```

So why doesn't this configuration pass the 2020 'parameter' to the api endpoint? It works when I make a configuration like this:

```
location = /api/2020 {
   proxy_pass http://api/2020;
}
```

But the problem is that it's a parameter so it can possibly be any number, how to solve this?

I've read other posts, but I ask this question again to get a broader understanding of the passing possibilities for parameters. Is it really necessary to use Regex for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove exact matching, just use

```
location /api/ {
   proxy_pass http://api/;
}
```

without any regexes.

Comment: This was it, i wasn't aware of the = meaning exact matching

Answer (score 1):

You are using "=" regex for comparison so It will find same url so please read the below code & change your configuration.

```
 location ~ ^/(api)/ {
                proxy_pass http://api;
        }
```

After the above changes restart your nginx server & you dont need to write separate code for all the APIs.

I hope!
It will resolve your problem.

Comment: Is it a problem if the real api has an extra route, like: location ~ ^/(api/foo)/ ?

Comment: No, There will be no error if you add extra routes.
Example :- https://serverfault.com/questions/650117/serving-multiple-proxy-endpoints-under-location-in-nginx

Comment: `=` isn't a regex, and your answer won't work, it would proxy the `/api/2020` request to `http://api/api/2020` while OP wants it to be proxied to `http://api/2020`.

Comment: @IvanShatsky Thanks for correction, But it will redirect using prefix {/api/} to that service and dont need to rewrite the code for all the API routes.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to solve:

```
location / {
   proxy_pass http://internal_addr:port$request_uri;   
}
```

***Example for a IP/PORT: 172.168.1.1:3000, internal server:***

```
location / {
   proxy_pass http://172.168.1.1:3000$request_uri;   
}
```

By doing this, everything that the external client requests to nginx after the `/` (routes, parameters, etc.) nginx will forward to the internal server in exactly the same way.

---

If you have more than one internal server, you can use something like this:

**In server1(IP/PORT: 172.168.1.1:3333):**

```
location /app1 {
```

proxy_pass http://172.168.1.1:3333$request_uri;
}

That is:

Client Request to Nginx: exemple.com/app1/login.php?x=y

Nginx Will send the request to server1 as /app1/login.php?x=y

**In server2 (IP/PORT: 172.168.1.2:4444):**

```
location /app2 {
```

proxy_pass http://172.168.1.2:4444$request_uri;
}

That is:

Client Request to Nginx: exemple.com/app2/login.php?x=y

Nginx Will send the request to server2 as /app2/login.php?x=y